# Summing two objects without altering either

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

In the slow progress of the project that generated my all-but-tumbleweed [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134879/building-nested-object-structures-from-csv-input) I've needed to make sum-unions (any better term?) of simple objects where key:value is `sizeClass:tally` -- I need the union of all `sizeClasses`, summing their values where they're the same.  I came up with this and I wonder whether anyone sees anything terrible about it or has a slicker way.

```
function mashObj(objA,objB) {
  var objC = {};
  var [ak,av] = deval(objA);
  var [bk,bv] = deval(objB);
  for (var i=0;i<ak.length;i++) {
    objC[ak[i]] = av[i];
  }
  for (i=0;i<bk.length;i++) {
    objC[bk[i]] = (objC[bk[i]] || 0) + bv[i];
  }
  return objC;
}
function deval(obj) {
  var ks = [];
  var vs = [];
  for (var k in obj) {
    ks.push(k);
    vs.push(Math.round(obj[k]));
  }
  return [ks, vs];
}
```

These functions are purpose-built, plenty of assumption about what's coming in, so there's been no attempt at generalizing.  I go through `deval()` rather than doing a `for..in` because I also need to preserve the original two objects -- I've been getting into a lot of trouble with the spooky-manipulation-at-a-distance problem.

By "sum-union" all I mean is that I might have something like:

```
plot1 = {2:4, 5:12, 7:3};
plot2 = {2:1, 4:3, 5:3};
  // and what I want to get is
total == {2:5, 4:3, 5:15, 7:3};
```

I assume that somewhere in math, logic or CS, probably all three, there's a proper term for this.

Comment: I am trying to grasp what sum-unions is according to your description. Could you show an example for the benefit of others

Comment: Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vx50suhb/)

Comment: @Tushar Yours seems decidedly neater.  I'll need to unriddle the argument to filter() -- but good!  That's what I was posting for.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tushar, that was a nice example . Cheers Mate

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using ES2015 destructuring assignments you can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
function mashObj(a, b) {
    var sum = {};
    new Set([...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)])
        .forEach(k => sum[k] = Math.round(a[k]||0) + Math.round(b[k]||0));
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few improvement as the code is quite small.

You can shorten your `deval()` to this:

```js
function deval(obj) {
  var arr = $.map(obj, function(value) {
    return value;
  });
  return [Object.keys(obj), arr];
}

plot1 = {2:4, 5:12, 7:3};
plot2 = {2:1,4:3,5:3};

console.log(deval(plot1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is an `Object.keys()` that creates an array of all the keys of an object. Note, there is also an  [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), which is an experimental technology with little support in all browsers. 
In place of that,  I used a `map()` as shown in this example [Get object values without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16731238/5274722).